# How to get a part of docx file as image, not whole page

Tags: c#, image, ms-word, crystal-reports, ole

I have been trying to insert a docx file contents into crystal reports. (In Crystal Reports if I insert OLE object and select a docx file, program imports only the used part of the word file, not the whole page.)

I have searched to convert Word document to image, but all I found was about getting a whole page or a specific image in a page. In my case I can have text and also line objects and maybe some graphic files in maybe 6 - 7 paragraphs. And only used part of the page(6 - 7 paragraphs) should be my image file.

Our customers are using this Word files as a header of the report. For now the only way I can do is to have screen shoot of the design. And it doesn't always look good. Is there a way to get this part as image?

Note: I can't use directly doc file in crystal reports, I need to have the data in SQL database. So it has to be graphic file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the [Selection.CopyAsPicture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.copyaspicture) method which works the same way as the `Copy` method. Basically you need to select the required content in a Word `Document` and then use this method to take a picture of selected content and keep it in a memory for further usage. For example, the following example copies the contents of the active document as a picture and pastes it as a picture at the end of the document:

```vb
Sub CopyPasteAsPicture() 
 ActiveDocument.Content.Select 
 With Selection 
   .CopyAsPicture 
   .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd 
   .PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture 
 End With 
End Sub
```

In C# you could use the same properties and methods, the Word object model is common for all kind of applications.

Comment: Thanks, it works as you said. Just need to decide the selection range. But I still wonder how crystal reports doing this that smooth. It shouldn't be the same technique :). I think it is a different question, so thank you.